# Multiple nested IIFs

Tags: nested, switch-statement, iif

I think I need a nested IIF in SSRS for my goal as written in pseudo code below:

```
If GoalType.Value = ImplementED And
SavingsGoal.Value <= ImplementEDSavings.Value OR 
If GoalType.Value = ImplementABLE And
SavingsGoal.Value <= ImplementABLESavings.Value 
Then display zero dollars

ELSE

If GoalType = ImplementED And 
SavingsGoal.Value > ImplementEDSavings.value Then
Display SavingsGoal.Value minus ImplementABLESavings

ELSE

If GoalType = ImplementABLE And
SavingsGoal.Value > ImplementABLESavings.Value Then
Display SavingsGoal.Value minus ImplementABLESavings
```

I've gotten this much to work:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implemented" AND 
Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives") OR 
(First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implementable" AND 
Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")),0,
Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") - Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives"))
```

All I need to to figure out how to get that final "ELSE" in there, realizing I need some more IIFs or Switches or something... I've tried several ways and my deadline is officially tight. Thanks to anyone who can help. Note that I'm really new at SSRS reports.

UPDATE:
Here are a couple of methods that I've tried. I keep getting this error with every try:
error BC30057 Too many arguments to 'Public Function IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As Object' SSRS

=iif(
    (First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implemented" AND 
    Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")),0
    ) OR

iif(
    (First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implementable" AND 
    Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")),0,
    ) OR

iif(
    (First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implemented" AND 
    Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") > Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")),
    Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") - Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives"),
    ) OR

iif(
    (First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implementable AND 
    Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") > Sum(Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")),
    Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") - Sum(Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")
    )

OR

=IIF(First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implemented" AND 
 Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives") OR 
 (First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implementable" AND 
 Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")),0,

Switch(First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implemented",
 Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") - Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives") 
Switch(First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implementable",
 Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") - Sum(Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives"))))

personal comment, if these systems wouldn't assume that everyone is a born programmer and give errors that speak English, I wouldn't have to come to these sites for translations. Ok, soapbox over. Thanks again to anyone who can help

Comment: This comment box confuses me - please delete this post

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight modification on your first update.

```
=iif( (First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implemented" AND Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")),0,
iif( (First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implementable" AND Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") <= Sum(Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")),0,  
iif( (First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implemented" AND Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") > Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")), Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") - Sum(Fields!ImplementedSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives"), 
iif( (First(Fields!GoalType.Value, "Project_Details") = "Implementable" AND Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") > Sum(Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives")), Sum(Fields!SavingsGoal.Value, "Project_Details") - Sum(Fields!ImplementableSavings.Value, "dsInitiatives") ) 
)))
```

Instead of using OR's, I've nested the subsequent iif statements in the false argument of the preceding iif. About that error you were getting, "Too many arguements" - you actually had too few.

Here's the first (simplified) block of your code:

```
=iif( First(GoalType) = "Implemented" AND Sum(SavingsGoal) <= Sum(ImplementedSavings),0 ) OR
```

Note that you have the Boolean correct, but you only supply a single argument afterwards "0" for the true. The iif needs two arguments, a true and false. In your instance, you want the next iif statement to be in the false (else) portion.

Updated code:

```
=iif( First(GoalType) = "Implemented" AND Sum(SavingsGoal) <= Sum(ImplementedSavings),0, iif(boolean, true, iif(boolean, true, false)))
```

Comment: You're an angel, Thank you Galfni. The latest "Updated Code" you sent did the trick! Enjoy your weekend.